# No access to a parameter needed in a predicate

Tags: java, lambda, predicate, functional-interface

I have the following two methods method1 and method2 :

```
public void method1(){
List<Integer> p = ...

listRefCtl.forEach(x->
                    x.getDomains().forEach(domain ->
                            domaine.getRisks().forEach(risk ->
                                    attribution.getFicheControles().removeIf(fc ->
                                                            !DateUtil.isBetween(fc.getT().getDateT(), p.get(0), p.get(1)))))
                            )
                    )
            );
}


public void method2(){
List<Integer> p = ...

listRefCtl.forEach(x->
                    x.getDomains().forEach(domain ->
                            domaine.getRisks().forEach(risk ->
                                    attribution.getFicheControles().removeIf(fc ->
                                                            !DateUtil.isAfter(date1, date2)))
                            )
                    )
            );
}
```

As you can see, it's the same piece of code except that i have two different predicates inside the removeIf method which are :

```
!DateUtil.isBetween(fc.getT().getDateT(), p.get(0), p.get(1))
```

and

```
!DateUtil.isAfter(date1, date2)
```

i would like to extract a method like this

```
public void method1(){
    List<Integer> p = ...
    extractedMethod(() -> !DateUtil.isBetween(fc.getT().getDateT(), p.get(0), p.get(1)));
}

public void method2(){
    List<Integer> p = ...
    extractedMethod(() -> !DateUtil.isAfter(date1, date2));
}

public void extractedMethod(predicate){
listRefCtl.forEach(x->
                    x.getDomains().forEach(domain ->
                            domaine.getRisks().forEach(risk ->
                                    attribution.getFicheControles().removeIf(predicate)))
                            );
}
```

the problem is that i don't know how to pass the "fc" object in the "extractedMethod" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `date1` and `date2` here? And what is the type of `fc`?

Comment: The answer bellow was accepted. Thank you @Kirill Simonov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) takes a `Predicate<? super E>`, where `E` is whatever type is in the collection returned by `getFicheControles()`. For the sake of this answer, let that be `Foo`.

```
public void method1() {
    List<Integer> p = ...
    extractedMethod(fc -> !DateUtil.isBetween(fc.getT().getDateT(), p.get(0), p.get(1)));
}
```

```
public void method2() {
    List<Integer> p = ...
    extractedMethod(fc -> !DateUtil.isAfter(date1, date2));
}
```

```
public void extractedMethod(Predicate<Foo> filter) {
    listRefCtl.forEach(x->
            x.getDomains().forEach(domain ->
                    domaine.getRisks().forEach(risk ->
                            attribution.getFicheControles().removeIf(filter)
                            )));
}
```

Comment: Passing the Generic E is what i was missing. Thank you very much @Andreas